# Why do I keep getting more than one item in my list when retrieving information with BS4 and requests?

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

Webpage = requests.get('https://www.brainyquote.com/quote_of_the_day')

soup = BeautifulSoup( Webpage.content, 'html.parser')

qoute = soup.find(class_='qotd-q-cntr')
words = [qoute.find('a').text for item in qoute]


print(words)
```

When printing the variable `words` I get the same quote appearing three times in my list but I want to just get it one time. my output is similar to the following

```
['qoute','qoute','qoute']
```

I'm looking to get it to be something like this

```
['qoute']
```

Comment: Have you researched how to remove duplicates from a list?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are scraping via `class` attribute and the one you gave is the one for **all** the quotes when you inspect that website.

[image: Quotes_1]

Instead, search for something more specific. Like an `h2` tag with `class` `qotd-h2` and `innerText` "Quote of the Day".

[image: Quotes_2]

Then from getting that anchor element you can traverse the DOM to get to the quote.

Example

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

Webpage = requests.get('https://www.brainyquote.com/quote_of_the_day')

soup = BeautifulSoup( Webpage.content, 'html.parser')

#? Find the quote of the day title
anchor = soup.find('h2', class_='qotd-h2', text="Quote of the Day")
quoteDiv = anchor.parent.find(class_="clearfix") #? The div surrounding the quote
quote = quoteDiv.find(title="view quote") #? The quote tag

print(quote.text)
```